# C# TransformBlock is not executed after calling Complete function

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, tpl-dataflow

I have this code snippet:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var printResult = new ActionBlock<int>(x =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    });
    var countBytes = new TransformBlock<int, int>(
        new Func<int, int>((x)=> { return 2 * x; }));
    countBytes.LinkTo(printResult, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    countBytes.Completion.ContinueWith(delegate { printResult.Complete(); });
    countBytes.Complete();
    printResult.Completion.Wait();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I expected that the `TransformBlock` code of

```
return 2*x
```

will run, and then print the result, but in fact, nothing is printed. I set a break point inside the

```
printResult
```

function object on the `Console.WriteLine` but it was not stepped in.

Why nothing is printed, where did I get wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: You haven't posted anything to either block

Comment: And the line `countBytes.Completion.ContinueWith(delegate { printResult.Complete(); });` does what `PropagateCompletion = true` already does

Comment: You should add `countBytes.Post(123);` before calling `countBytes.Complete();`

Comment: The code block seems to be copied right from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-perform-action-when-a-dataflow-block-receives-data and it is therefore interesting that the following line is missing: countBytes.Post(tempFile);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the setting to tell `countBytes` to propagate completion to the linked block (trying to use a ContinueWith() to complete a linked block is the wrong way to do this).

Also, if you don't post anything to the pipeline, there won't be any output.

Try this instead:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var printResult = new ActionBlock<int>(x =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    });

    var countBytes = new TransformBlock<int, int>(new Func<int, int>((x) => { return 2 * x; }));

    countBytes.LinkTo(printResult, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    countBytes.Post(1);
    countBytes.Completion.ContinueWith(task => Console.WriteLine("countBytes has completed"));
    printResult.Completion.ContinueWith(task => Console.WriteLine("printResult has completed"));
    countBytes.Complete();
    printResult.Completion.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If you run that, the output is:

```
2
countBytes has completed
Done
printResult has completed
```

(Note how "printResult has completed" is output *after* "Done". This is because the continuation is scheduled AFTER `printResult.Completion` is signalled.)

If you comment out the `new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true }` like so:

```
countBytes.LinkTo(printResult /*, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true } */);
```

then the output will be:

```
2
countBytes has completed
```

Note that "Done" is not printed, because `printResult.Completion.Wait()` never returns if the completion is not propagated to that block.